# Hotspot- Facebook authentication on mobile

Tags: android, windows, mobile, facebook-social-plugins, hotspot

I have setup a Mikrotik router that creates a hotspot where you can authenticate by normal login or by logging with the user's facebook account. This works on laptop and desktops (with windows OS).

Once I tried it on mobile devices (with Windows and Android OS), the user is redirected to the facebook's official login page to insert their facebook account information, once they press "ENTER", every mobile device I tried holds on a white page (like in the picture) ---->[Mobile Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5gKq.png)

I am not very familiar with mobile related topics. Does anyone have an ideia of why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in our way (simple way):

1. Facebook app connects to clients account and, for example, checks if user in specific groups
2. Facebook app send to your server  clients MAC
3. Your server puts MAC to radius
4. Radius hotspot authorization
5. Client can use internet

This solutions works for more than 1300 mikrotiks and business